# Referenced Excel workbook in the code is nowhere to be seen in taskbar

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to open a workbook from powerpoint using VBA. Although the workbook object is getting set but the workbook is no where to be seen. [ See snap at the end for clarity ]

*Code:*

```
Public Path As String

Sub CheckThisSub()

  Path = ActivePresentation.Path
  Debug.Print (Path & "\" & "QC_Log.xlsm") 'prints D:\QC\Test\QC_Log.xlsm

  Dim QCWbk As New Excel.Workbook
  Set QCWbk = Excel.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & "QC_Log.xlsm")
  'QCWbk is getting set but the excel QC_Log.xlsm is nowhere to be seen.

  Debug.Print QCWbk.Name                   'prints QC_Log.xlsm
  QCWbk.Windows.Item(1).Visible = True

' Rest of code

End sub
```

*Snap:*

[image: Snap]

Comment: Try using `QCWbk.Visible = True`. After creating the object, of course...

Comment: @FaneDuru   Tried that, but to no avail..... :(

Comment: Where in the code did you insert that line? Like I said, it must be after `Set QCWbk = ...', like I suggested... Does the code return an error?

Comment: @FaneDuru Tried that too but not working. Lately facing a lot of quirky issues with VBA.

Comment: Does the code return any error? Please use `Set QCWbk = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`. Then `QCWbk.Visible = True` followed by `QCWbk.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & "QC_Log.xlsm")`.

Comment: @FaneDuru   It worked. Thank you so much. Although I would like to understand, I had added excel libraries in the tools--> references, so to avoid the createobject stuff. Any idea why that doesn't work ?

Comment: The excel instance created in code is listed under background processes.

Comment: @KostasK. Okay. Wow...How do you guys know so much ?

Comment: 20 years of asking similar questions on forums like this. :)

Comment: Adding the necessary libraries may be necessary (or not) if you use early or late binding. It is enough to have Excel installed for late binding. I will write an answer, trying to describe some possibilities of creating Excel sessions or getting an existing one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, creating one Excel session can be done in different ways.

1. Since you modified your initial declaration from `Dim QCWbk As Excel.Workbook` to `Dim QCWbk As New Excel.Workbook` your code problem resides in the way you try setting Excel application. Your code tries to set a workbook, not the Excel application. A piece of working code starting from yours should be the next one:

```
Dim QCWbk As New Excel.Workbook, wb as Excel.Workbook, Path As String 'Using New the Excel COM object is already instantiated:

Path = ActivePresentation.Path
Set wb = QCWbk.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & "QC_Log.xlsm") 'the workbook is set in this way!
QCWbk.Visible = True
```

2. Excel application can be simple created without referencing Excel libraries. This is late binding way, but you do not benefit of intellisense offering the objects properties/methods:

```
Dim QCWbk As Object, wb as Object, Path As String '

Path = ActivePresentation.Path
Set QCWbk = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
QCWbk.Visible = True
Set wb = QCWbk.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & "QC_Log.xlsm") 'the workbook is set in this way!
```

3. You can use the early binding without pre-instantiate the COM object. You benefit of Intellisense offers, but you have to create the instance in a second step:

```
Dim QCWbk As Excel.Workbook, wb as Excel.Workbook, Path As String 'Using New the Excel COM object is already instantiated:

Path = ActivePresentation.Path
Set QCWbk = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
QCWbk.Visible = True 
Set wb = QCWbk.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & "QC_Log.xlsm") 'the workbook is set in this way!
```

4. You can get an existing Excel open session with the next code:

```
Dim QCWbk Excel.Workbook, wb as Excel.Workbook, Path As String

Path = ActivePresentation.Path

On Error Resume Next
 Set QCWbk = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
 If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
     MsgBox "No Excel Open session..."
     Exit Sub 'the code exists if only an open session is required...
 End If
 'Usually in such a case a new session is created (as above). Here is only the part showing how to use an existing session
 Set wb = QCWbk.Workbooks.Open(Path & "\" & "QC_Log.xlsm") 'the workbook is set in this way!
 QCWbk.Visible = True
```

5. An open Excel session can be found if you know the name of a workbook open in a specific session... For instance, if another application (SAP, for instance) exports such a workbook (named "Book1") in a new session, you can find that session in this way:

```
Dim Ex As Excel.Application
Set Ex = GetObject("Book1").Application

Debug.Print Application.ActiveWindow.hwnd, Ex.ActiveWindow.hwnd
```

6. Finally, you can identify all Excel open sessions using API (FindWindowEx, IIDFromString and AccessibleObjectFromWindow), but it is a little more complicated and need to be uses in specific circumstances...

Comment: Thank you so much. This was quite an enlightening session..... :)